# GOM player alternative for ubuntu?

Tags: sound, video, vlc

Is there a video player that can solve these problems??

When I use VLC, its audio system is a little annoying. During speaking, its volume is low. During action and fighting, its volume is high. I have to adjust during the movie. I searched how to adjust it. I saw some answers and followed them. It works on computer's audio system. Not with my TV. I watch movies from laptop with TV for bigger screen.
Another problem is, subtitle adjustment. VLC does not adjust subtitle with video. It adjusts Video with subtitle. When subtitle timing exceeds 1 second, the video becomes crash for 1 second.

Also in movies with two black lines at the top and bottom (19:10 ratio??), subtitle reposition does not go into the bottom black box. In GOM, the subtitle went into black box and does not disturb the movie too much.

Comment: are you using VLC snap version or apt?

Comment: how do I look for it?

Comment: https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-list-installed-packages-on-ubuntu

Comment: It was apt. It was apt version.